# Why doesn’t the mono $\emptyset \rightarrow A$ split in Sets?

Tags: category-theory

Why doesn’t the mono $\emptyset \rightarrow A$ split in Sets?

Since it’s mono we have $fg=fh \Rightarrow g=h$

If we assume it’s splittable then we have $k: A \rightarrow \emptyset$ such that $kf=1_{\emptyset}$.

Where is the contradiction?

Comment: Unless $A=\emptyset$, there are no functions $A\to\emptyset$.

Comment: Why can’t that be a function?

Comment: If $a\in A$ and $f:A\to\varnothing$ is a function then what should be $f(a)$? It must satisfy $f(a)\in\varnothing$ contradicting that $\varnothing$ has no elements.

Comment: Then why can $\emptyset \rightarrow A$ be a function?  Is it just vacuously true?

Comment: Yes. A function $f:B\to A$ is by definition a subset of $B\times A$ such that for every $b\in B$ there is a unique $a\in A$ such that $\langle b,a\rangle\in f$. If $B=\varnothing$ then this is vacuously true (only) for $f=\varnothing$. So $\varnothing$ is a function $\varnothing\to A$.

Comment: @DerekElkins Please consider relabeling your comment as an answer, so that the stackexchange software doesn't treat this as an unanswered question requiring more attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above in the comments, this is basically just a vacuous logic "trick." We can define a set function $f:\varnothing \to A$, since for every element $x\in \varnothing$, there exists a unique element $f(x)\in A$. In particular, since $\varnothing$ is empty, this condition is satisfied vacuously. On the other hand, if we could define a map $g:A\to \varnothing$, for $A\ne \varnothing$, we would be saying that for any $x\in A$ there exists a unique $g(x)\in \varnothing$. No such $g(x)$ could exist, since $\varnothing $ is empty.